# MySQL - Splitting a large text column into a subtable

Tags: mysql, split, procedure

I am working on a MySQL table which has been imported from a CSV for "tickets"

Table generally looks like

> Tickets(TicketID, Priority, .... Notes)

The Notes column is a bit of a disaster, and has a bunch of differently dated notes which are split by a delimiter of "--------"

A typical ticket would look like:

> Will Look into this later today.
>
> --------
>
> Looked into it. Needs fixing.
>
> --------
>
> Fixed 10/10/15

I want to split this large Notes column into a subtable with a table which looks like

> Notes(noteNo, TicketID, Note)

with each split note referencing the original TicketID in a separate row, and the NoteNo and TicketID being the composite primary key.

How would I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: It's a good idea to do this. I think I would simply write a small program (C# or whatever) to read the table and write the entries for the subtable.

Comment: This is rather a broad question. Doable with a stored procedure but rather difficult. Why not narrow it down but tagging with your favourite language.

Comment: additionally, have you made any changes to the data since it was imported from the CSV file?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I did not think of that! Thanks.

Comment: @e4c5 Yes, I have changed the table, so it would not be feasible to go back to the original CSV.

Do you mean like I should tag it with "Java"? Sorry, I am new to asking questions on SO. :-)

Comment: yes, if java is what you are using. Pity that the data has changed. This is easy to do with the CSV but harder with the tables